# Permission Denial: starting Intent requires <package name>

Tags: android, permissions, remote-access, permission-denied, openvpn

I have problem with running service from another app (I have both apps projects in Eclipse) through AIDL. Everytime when i'm using methods from the interface I get:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent
{cmp=de.blinkt.openvpn/.api.GrantPermissionsActivity } from ProcessRecord{42cfd9c0 
22519:com.xxx/u0a10093} (pid=22519, uid=10093) requires de.blinkt.openvpn.REMOTE_API.
```

I've looked everywhere and I didn't found any viable answer. How to fix it?

Comment: Post the code which is causing the problem. Just posting the error isn't enough.

Comment: I don't know which part of code would be helpful. GrantPermissionActivity in manifest in external app:

 <activity
            android:name=".api.GrantPermissionsActivity"
            android:permission="de.blinkt.openvpn.REMOTE_API" 
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: so you error on the side of avoidance? at a minimum, how about both AndroidManifest.xml files.

Comment: @mglisty : There will be more to the stacktrace than you've posted. Work out which part of your code is referenced in logcat and post that code. It will be mentioned something like com.yourpackage.yourclass

Comment: Damn, I've just removed permission and it worked. Now I have:
"11-14 13:06:48.009: W/ActivityManager(513): Unable to start service Intent { act=de.blinkt.openvpn.api.IOpenVPNStatusCallback } U=0: not found" error when I try to connect with IOpenVPNStatusCallback.

Answer (score 2):

To use the API you need first to call:

```
/** This permission framework is used  to avoid confused deputy style attack to the VPN
     * calling this will give null if the app is allowed to use the external API and an Intent
     * that can be launched to request permissions otherwise */
    Intent prepare (String packagename);
```

And you need to have in your Manifest:

```
<!-- Copy the <permission> block to your app when using the REMOTE API. Otherwise OpenVPN for
    Android needs to be installed first -->
<permission
    android:name="de.blinkt.openvpn.REMOTE_API"
    android:description="@string/permission_description"
    android:label="Control OpenVPN"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.NETWORK"
    android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />

<uses-permission android:name="de.blinkt.openvpn.REMOTE_API">
```

Note the comment before that permission...

Comment: Thank you, it's resolved. BTW: do you know how to register IOpenVPNStatusCallback? It's not another service, and I'm kinda confused with it.

Comment: Sure. You just do  private IOpenVPNStatusCallback mCallback = new IOpenVPNStatusCallback.Stub() {
@Override
  public void newStatus [...]

and call registerStatusCallback(mCallback)